# Batch convert OSM/PBF data

Tags: openstreetmap, ogr, ogr2ogr, batch

I need to import some OSM data about a region of Italy into a SHP file or Postgres DB, possibly with batch process.

I already use OGR2OGR to batch import data from SHP to Oracle and Postgres and I know that the tool supports many other formats. I would like to know where I can find a compiled version of OGR2OGR that support OSM/PBF data and how I should use it.

I was looking at FWTools but on the site documentation I cannot see anything about OSM/PBF support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new GDAL Version 1.10 supports Openstreetmap data:

http://www.gdal.org/ogr/drv_osm.html

If you are on Windows, you can get GDAL 1.10 precompiled from [Link](https://www.gisinternals.com/sdk.php).

OSGeo4W does not yet have the 1.10 version.

Comment: Thank you! I'll give it a try. Do I have to download the x64 version as I'm on Windows 7 x64 or does the x86 work right anyway?

Comment: I am not sure if and how 64bit GDAL works with a 32-bit Postgres Database. Apart from that I would suggest the x64 version; it might run faster and without some Gigabyte limits.